# Disable cursor moving from touch input

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

I'm working on an application that injects itself into games as an overlay for touch input in games designed without touch input in mind.

One of my problems is that whenever the user touches the screen, the cursor is moved there.

I can't figure out a way to prevent that from happening. I have `WH_MOUSE_LL` and `WH_MOUSE` hooked, and I'm rejecting anything that comes into the target program, but it doesn't prevent the movement itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to be good form to put your solution after you find it yourself, so anybody with the same problem can fix it. I ended up solving this by hooking GetCursorPos and SetCursorPos in the target process to emulate my own mouse. Although the mouse is still technically being moved by the OS, it no longer affects gameplay. If someone has a better solution, I'm all ears.

Comment: [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) may be a less intrusive way to achieve your goal. As far as I understand, it allows you to both monitor and filter input events. I don't know, though, if the raw input callback is executed before or after the system generates respective mouse input, to provide compatibility support for applications that do not provide a native touch interface. Those could be globally filtered out using a `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook, in case that's needed.

Comment: @Jos did you ever solve this?